# What kind of notation is this? someFunction([{key: value}, {key: value})

Tags: javascript, json

I came across a file with extension .json which is a part of a much larger project. The JSON file has content that looks something like this:

```
someFunction([
   {'key': 'value'},
   {'key': 'value'}
])
```

It this some particular notation type? Also, why is everything enclosed in a function?

I have some idea about JSON notation. The stuff inside the function is an array of object, whereas the file as a whole is not valid JSON notation.

I'm trying to extract the JSON object out of this file. For now, I'm able to achieve my results by obtaining a substring and then converting it back to JSON. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: This is like `console.log(1)` except you're passing in an array of two objects. Try it: `console.log([
   {'key': 'value'},
   {'key': 'value'}
])` and see what happens. Then think about what `someFunction` does instead of `console.log`, and there you go. This is an actual JS object, not JSON, which is a stringification of a JS object.

Comment: Are you using **Node.js** to read the file because JavaScript does not have an access to file system?

Answer (score 0):

That content isn't valid JSON.
You can verify it using any JSONLint e.g. [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

In order to obtain a Javascript object from the file that you mentioned you can do something like this:

```
someFunction = console.log

//content of the file
someFunction([
   {'key': 'value'},
   {'key': 'value'}
])
```